# Displaying the shipping method of the order in "Thank you" page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, I would like to display the name of chosen shipping method for the current order in "Thank you" (order received) page…

How can I get the name of this chosen shipping methods in Thank you page?

All I can get is the shipping address, instead I would like to display the shipping method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in **`WC_Abstract_Order`** available methods, you have [**`get_shipping_method()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_shipping_method) that is going to display the title of the shipping method used with your order.

Now you can use this method in your code with the **`$order`** object this way

```
echo $order->get_shipping_method();
```